# Cant store this JSON data in c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im tryig to create an application that uses the API from a site called backpack.tf.

Im facing a problem, I have a file for where the data will be stored:

```
class currencyData
{
    public CurrencyResponse currencyResponse { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyResponse 
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public int current_time { get; set; }
    public int raw_usd_value { get; set; }
    public int usd_currency { get; set; }
    public int usd_currency_index { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, CurrencyPrices> items { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyPrices
{
    public int currency { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public int value_high { get; set; }
    public int value_raw { get; set; }
    public int value_high_raw { get; set; }
    public int last_update { get; set; }
    public int difference { get; set; }
}
```

and basically my code for trying to store the JSON data is this:

```
//make call to the API and retrieve JSON data
char[] array1 = { };
char[] array2 = { };
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
System.Net.WebClient client2 = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("key-price", "application/json");
client2.Headers.Add("item-data", "application/json");
//get the JSON data.
string test = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.UploadData("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetCurrencies/v1/?key=54972a10b88d885f748b4956&appid=440&compress=1", "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(array1)));
string currencyJSON = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client2.UploadData("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4/?key=54972a10b88d885f748b4956&appid=440&compress=1", "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(array2)));

//deserialize json data and store it in rootObject.cs
rootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootObject>(test);
//same as above but store itt in currencyData.cs
currencyData currencyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<currencyData>(currencyJSON);

Response response = obj.response;
CurrencyResponse currencyResponse = currencyData.currencyResponse;
//check if the API responds, If not we can display an error message
if (response.success == 1 ) {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Currency> kvp in response.currencies)
    {
        string currencyName = kvp.Key;
        Currency currency = kvp.Value;
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CurrencyPrices> currencyDataDict in currencyResponse.items)
    {
        string itemName = currencyDataDict.Key;
        CurrencyPrices currencyPrices = currencyDataDict.Value;
    }

    Currency kek = new Currency();
    outputBox.Text = test;
}
```

rootObject:

```
class rootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public int current_time { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Currency> currencies { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public int quality { get; set; }
    public int priceindex { get; set; }
    public string single { get; set; }
    public string plural { get; set; }
    public int round { get; set; }
    public string craftable { get; set; }
    public string tradable { get; set; }
    public int active { get; set; }
    public int defindex { get; set; }
}
```

Now my problem is the data isnt being retrieved in the second API call and if i remove the second foreach loop it will output the variable Test which contains JSON data, However if i keep the second foreach loop in it will print nothing..

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad wording etc.
[Backpack.tf API doccumentation](http://backpack.tf/api/prices)

Comment: It think it is not bad idea to use async call for your network requests and see if it works.

Comment: What is the structure of your "rootObject" class ?

Comment: @persianDeveloper Updated my post with rootObject structure.

Comment: Can you please provide samples of JSON that you retrieve from calling `backpack.tf`...

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov Links are in the code.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your `System.Net.WebClient` objects in a `using` statement.

Comment: That api key in your code is supposed to be private. I suggest refreshing your api key so nobody goes about doing bad stuff with it.

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with `currencyData`:

1. The JSON returned does not actually match the documentation (good job there Backpack.tf):

   1.1. The field named `"Untradable"` is actually returned as `"Non-Tradable"`

   1.2. The field named `"Uncraftable"` is actually returned as `"Non-Craftable"`.

   1.3. The `"Craftable"` objects are supposed to be returned in a dictionary of quantity to price data.   In fact, they are *sometimes* returned as an *array*:

   ```
         "Craftable": [
           {
             "currency": "metal",
             "value": 1.33,
             "last_update": 1417451879,
             "difference": -0.11
           }
         ]

       But they are *sometimes* returned as a dictionary!

         "Craftable": {
           "10": {
             "currency": "usd",
             "value": 101.49,
             "value_high": 124.04,
             "last_update": 1362682641,
             "difference": 34.719
           },
           "11": {
             "currency": "earbuds",
             "value": 1.4,
             "last_update": 1406474947,
             "difference": 31.236,
             "value_high": 1.8
           },
   ```
2. You have several fields declared as `int` which can have fractional data.  They need to be changed to something else, for instance `decimal`.
3. Your data model does not match the documented model, which is several levels deeper than yours.

The following code and objects for `currencyData` read both the JSON shown in the documentation and the JSON actually returned by the call, since I suppose both must be handled.  Note also the following [qualification](http://backpack.tf/api/prices) from the documentation:

> Only one request can be made to this API per minute per API key. Additionally, the response is cached and updated every 10 minutes.

So, make sure you're not getting prices too often.

```
[DataContract]
public class currencyData
{
    [DataMember(Name="response")]
    public CurrencyResponse response { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class CurrencyResponse
{
    public CurrencyResponse()
    {
        this.items = new Dictionary<string,ItemPrices>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int success { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long current_time { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal raw_usd_value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string usd_currency { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long usd_currency_index { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Dictionary<string, ItemPrices> items { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ItemPrices
{
    public ItemPrices()
    {
        this.prices = new Dictionary<long, ItemTradablePrices>();
    }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Dictionary<long, ItemTradablePrices> prices { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ItemTradablePrices
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ItemCraftablePrices Tradable { get; set; }

    // Sometimes appears as "Non-Tradable", sometimes "Untradable".  Handle both
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ItemCraftablePrices Untradable { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Non-Tradable", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    ItemCraftablePrices NonTradable
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            Untradable = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ItemCraftablePrices
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PrinceIndexDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<long, PriceIndex> Craftable { get; set; }

    // Sometimes appears as "Non-Craftable", sometimes "Uncraftable".  Handle both
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PrinceIndexDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<long, PriceIndex> Uncraftable { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="Non-Craftable", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PrinceIndexDictionaryConverter))]
    Dictionary<long, PriceIndex> NonCraftable
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            Uncraftable = value;
        }
    }
}

public class PrinceIndexDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<long, PriceIndex>);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dict = existingValue as Dictionary<long, PriceIndex>;
        if (dict == null)
            dict = new Dictionary<long, PriceIndex>();

        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                List<PriceIndex> list = new List<PriceIndex>();
                serializer.Populate(reader, list);
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                    dict[i] = list[i];
                break;

            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                serializer.Populate(reader, dict);
                break;

            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("Unexpected token type " + reader.TokenType.ToString());
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PriceIndex
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public decimal value { get; set; }
    public decimal value_high { get; set; }
    public decimal value_raw { get; set; }
    public decimal value_high_raw { get; set; }
    public long last_update { get; set; }
    public decimal difference { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
    public currencyData SendCurrencyQuery()
    {
        //make call to the API and retrieve JSON data
        char[] array2 = { };

        using (var client2 = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            client2.Headers.Add("item-data", "application/json");
            //get the JSON data.
            string currencyJSON = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client2.UploadData("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4/?key=54972a10b88d885f748b4956&appid=440&compress=1", "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(array2)));

            //same as above but store itt in currencyData.cs
            var currencyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<currencyData>(currencyJSON);

            return currencyData;
        }
    }
```